# Switch menu color for current part of page

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making a one-page site where the menu is fixed, so when the user clicks a link it scrolls down to that part of the page. The menu link of the section the user is on should have a different color. For this I have the class "current." I'm trying to make this change with jQuery addClass() and removeClass(), but am having no luck. The code I have so far is below.

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
    $(".about").click(function(){
        $(".home").removeClass("current");
        $(".about").addClass("current");
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

menu HTML:

```
<nav id="nav_list">
<ul>
<li class="home current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="portfolio"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
<li class="testimonials"><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
<li class="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

div HTML:

```
<div id="about" class="page">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
</div>
```

(There is a div to go with each menu link.)

**EDIT2**

css:

```
#nav_list .current a{
color: #D4D1FA;
}
```

I noticed that if I remove the #nav_list, I don't see a change in color from the start.

Comment: it is working here.http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/Vx3up/

Comment: Then why won't it work where I'm using it...

Comment: Do you have a live link we can check? Maybe you could add some CSS - it may be a problem with that, rather than the class not being added. Does it work as expected when you add the class yourself?

Comment: I don't have a live version of the page, sorry.

Comment: And what happens if you load the page with `about current` rather than `home current` - does it work as expected then?

Comment: Then the about link gets the "current" color, but the jQuery still has no effect. Also, see my second edit in my original post.

Comment: ok - in that case  would check that there are no errors in any of your JQuery code as this would stop the functions from running. I'm not sure if we could provide much more help if you couldn't reproduce the problem in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or put the site somewhere live for us to check in more detail.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts To answer your question that is now gone, I do have an #about, but only a background color is set.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I deleted it. When you said that it worked when you applied the class at the very start, that answered the question for me

Comment: I think this has to do with the css. So what if I just forget about the .current and change the color of the menu link that is clicked through jQuery?

Comment: It is nothing to do with the CSS. You have said if you start the page with `about current` then the `about` link gets the colour as set in `current`. So the problem is with your JQuery, but not the JQuery that you have given us - there must be an error with your code somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it removes the current class from all list items and adds the class to the clicked one.

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

To answer your specific use case though. Set your links to display as block. This causes them to fill their list item containers. Then monitor the link click instead of the list item click. What was happening before was that clicking on the link did not trigger a click on the list item container, so your add/remove class code probably was never firing. By making it fill the area you capture all clicks.

http://jsfiddle.net/hkZsL/

css

```
a { text-decoration: none; display: block; }
li { padding: 4px; border: 1px solid gray; width: 100px; float: left; }
.current { border: 1px solid red; }
```

javascript

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Connor - just updated my answer, see if that makes more sense

Comment: I already had it set to display: block. I also tried the updated code, but it's still not working.

Comment: @Connor - can you define 'not working.' Class isn't added? Class is added but style doesn't changed?

Comment: The style isn't changing (the new color specified by .current is not showing).

Comment: It sounds like the problem is your css and not your jQuery. If you use Chrome or FF w/ firebug you can right mouse button on the list item and choose 'inspect element.' In the popup debugger window expand the 'styles' box and see where the style is getting overridden